# How to login in app using facebook WP8?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, facebook-login

i am trying to use my facbook account to login in windows phone 8 application .i need my  basic account info like my name email and password etc to proceed in my application . but i could not find a simple solution or any help for this . the solutions i found are too much complex for my understanding if any one give me a link or an anything . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a step by step solution in the Windows Phone [Dev blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login.aspx).

Should be as easy as installing the Facebook SDK for .NET from Nuget, setting some stuff on the App.manifest file and initiate the login process:

```
Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.LoginWithApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

As eshaham mentioned you should have the Facebook API to integrate with your application. Have a look over [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/wFace-windows-phone-7-facebook-integration-part-1.aspx) for the steps in detail.